# events.js throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, passport.js, passport-local

**edit 1**

Got it

```
// Reset Password Token link :get
router.get('/users/reset-password/:token', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      return res.redirect(302, '/users/new-password');
    }

    res.redirect(301, 'reset-password', {
      user: req.user
    });
  });
});

router.get('/users/new-password', function(req, res) {
  res.render('new-password', {
    pageTitle: 'New Password',
    User: req.user
  });
});
```

I had to specify a get route, but this seems really un secure as I don't want anyone just accessing this page, maybe I'm overthinking it?

--

**Original Question**

Currently I'm setting up a reset password system system, the email is sending and  a url with a token is being generated, however when I click the link to go to the new password page I'm getting the following

```
Fri Jan 12 2018 23:49:37 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /users/reset-password/23afd201c93945bfec7131801b377ea92edfc1fa
express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead routes/users.js:298:9
events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: [object Object]
```

Here is my route

```
// Reset Password Token link :get
router.get('/users/reset-password/:token', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      return res.redirect('/users/new-password');
    }

    res.redirect('/users/reset-password', {
      user: req.user
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the [doc for `res.redirect()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect).  It takes two parameters, an optional status code and a path.  There is no parameter for an object like you are trying to use.  So, either use `res.redirect('/users/reset-password')` or `res.redirect(302, '/users/reset-password')`.  If you want to put a query string in the URL, then put that into the path itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 See the above edit to the question

Comment: I don't understand what you think the question still is?  Your first edit still shows the illegal form of arguments for `res.redirect()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm overthinking it then, so regarding my next issue, it's strange, would you kindly take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236220/cannot-reset-password-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @jfriend00 worked

```
Look at the doc for res.redirect(). It takes two parameters, an optional status code and a path. There is no parameter for an object like you are trying to use. So, either use res.redirect('/users/reset-password') or res.redirect(302, '/users/reset-password'). If you want to put a query string in the URL, then put that into the path itself. – jfriend00 14 mins ago
```